# Rails + Nginx - why i should use fail_timeout=0 for multiple nodes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, devops, unicorn, nginx-upstreams

In nginx example config file here https://github.com/defunkt/unicorn/blob/master/examples/nginx.conf
you may see that:

```
# The only setting we feel strongly about is the fail_timeout=0
# directive in the "upstream" block.  max_fails=0 also has the same
# effect as fail_timeout=0 for current versions of nginx and may be
# used in its place.
```

As I understand, they think that all users will get `504 Bad Request` error in case of one server in upstream block if one of the request was killed by timeout or returned something that considered as a bad requset (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_next_upstream).

So in `upstream` block they have:

```
  upstream app_server {
    # fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
    # to return a good HTTP response (in case the unicorn master nukes a
    # single worker for timing out).

    # for UNIX domain socket setups:
    server unix:/path/to/.unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;

    # for TCP setups, point these to your backend servers
    # server 192.168.0.7:8080 fail_timeout=0;
    # server 192.168.0.8:8080 fail_timeout=0;
    # server 192.168.0.9:8080 fail_timeout=0;
  }
```

I am using `least_conn` directive in `upstream` block. So if one of unicorns down it will very fast answer with, for example, 500 error. And because of that 99% of all requests will be send to this node. In other words, if one node down - the whole app is down.

I am thinking of trying something like that:

```
 upstream app_server {
    least_conn;
    server 192.168.0.7:8080 fail_timeout=10s max_fails=5;
    server 192.168.0.8:8080 fail_timeout=10s max_fails=5;
    server 192.168.0.9:8080 fail_timeout=10s max_fails=5;
}
```

According to nginx doc (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#server) it means that one of the servers will be marked as DOWN for  next 10 second it it will send 5 bad answers in 10 second. I do not see any flaws. What do you think? I barely found any examples where fail_timeout is not 0.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but thought I'd answer since it became relevant to me recently.

It's pretty easy for bots to send misconfigured junk to a server and have it respond with an error code.  This results in nginx taking all your servers down when the bots hit it decently hard.

`fail_timeout=0` just has it re-check every time, which doesn't seem to come with much of a disadvantage.